# CSS Column - Zoom doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have 3 CSS columns. I use this CSS for it:

```
.articles {
  margin-top: 60px;
  -webkit-columns: 3 220px;
     -moz-columns: 3 220px;
          columns: 3 220px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
     -moz-column-gap: 5px;
          column-gap: 5px;
}

.articles > .col {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Now I want to zoom column on hover, but when I add code to zoom:

```
.articles > .col {
  ...
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease; /* Firefox */
      -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease; /* IE 9 */
       -o-transition: all 0.8s ease; /* Opera */
          transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.articles > .col:hover {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.10); /* Safari and Chrome */
     -moz-transform:scale(1.10); /* Firefox */
      -ms-transform:scale(1.10); /* IE 9 */
       -o-transform:scale(1.10); /* Opera */
          transform:scale(1.10);
}
```

Column zooms slowly and when it stop zooming it go under another colimn and push all columns down, in new line.

How I can zoom column but not to change positions of other columns in container?

EDIT: HTML Code

```
<div class="articles">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="uploads/1.jpg" alt="Image">
     <span>
       <span class="fav"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
       <span class="date">17.08.2000</span>
       <h3>Title</h3>
       <a href="#">Link</a>
     </span>
   </div>
   ....
   ....
   ....
 </div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/239L29nq/1/) with my code.

Comment: Can you share your full code including HTML please.

Comment: Edited with HTML code

Comment: I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/239L29nq/), but I can't see the problem you're describing. So could you post a complete example, that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/239L29nq/1/ This is problem

Comment: @MiljanIlic Oh, you added a lot more css to the fiddle than you had in your question originally. I'm not sure what causes it yet, but I do see that a) it works fine in Mozilla, while having problems in Chrome, and b) not all the `transform`s and `transition`s have vendor prefixes. You may want to look into that.

Comment: Oh yes, it works in Firefox. Do you have any suggestion how to fix?